# command to add the port 80 to the sftpgo service

Tags: linux, linux-networking, sftp

While doing sftpgo setup on linux, getting below error, what I believe is we might need to add the 80 port to sftpgo service. But not getting command that we can use to add the port to the service, configurations looks good and have compared them with one existing setup and don't see any discrepancy. Would appreciate if someone can suggest the **command to add the port 80 to the sftpgo service**

`Error: {"level":"error","time":"2021-12-08T07:50:14.011","sender":"service","message":"could not start HTTP server: listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied"}`

Comment: To be able to bind to ports below 1000 you need to start the process as root.

Comment: the process is started as root, i have cross checked that

Comment: What distribution are you using? Selinux could also need the cause for such an error.

Comment: We are running this on amazon linux and have sftpgo running on same type of server and without any changes, compared both the configurations as well, but still getting this error

Answer (score 1):

SFTPGo author here,

please add the `cap_net_bind_service capability` on the sftpgo binary using this command:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/bin/sftpgo
```

please take a look at the doc [here](https://github.com/drakkan/sftpgo/blob/main/docs/full-configuration.md#binding-to-privileged-ports) for more details.

You can open a GitHub issue/discussion and provide more details if this does not fix the problem